Django and IIS (wfastcgi.py, httpPlatform or ...)
I need to run next some years Django on IIS.
I found two ways
1. httpPlatform + runserver
wsgi.multithread:True
wsgi.multiprocess:False

The solution is multithreaded, working almost well, low resources, good performance. 2*5 processes can solve something like 1500req/second.
But:

IIS server returns HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway sometimes during app poll recycle. Not so often, but...

Eventviewer says:



HttpPlatformHandler: "Recursion too deep; the stack overflowed."`


Django runserver documentation says in big letters:


DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING


some sites said


HttpPlatformHandler has been replaced by ASP.NET Core Module

And HttpPlatformHandler is not a part of IIS.
2. fastCGI + wfastcgi
wsgi.multithread:False
wsgi.multiprocess:True

This solution is a single threaded, working well, with no error, even if recycle or hi load occurs. But consume high resources: 1500req = 1500 running processes, 100GB of memory for almost none. Big amount of running processes means big system heap consumptions, load global variables, resources, imports ... again and again.
Some sites say, of course:

wfastcgi is essentially deprecated ...

So - is there an effective and reliable way to run Django under IIS, which will last over some Windows versions from 2019, 2022 and next few at least 5-10 years?
Is there some port from .Net to Django, ASP.Net core to Django? Or should I do it?
I did several performance tests of two ports of Django to IIS and analysis on it.
I expect advise what way to go next.

https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-django-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ You still need to read more about the topic.

Thanks, Lex
I tried uvicorn, as on the page. I use
inline arguments="-m uvicorn _project.asgi:application"
with next simple test django view:
def test_view(request, uri):
out = '%s %s' % (executable,argv)
sleep(1)
return HttpResponse(out)
It says:
wsgi.multithread:True
But isn't. It can handle exactly 1 (one) request/second per process
If I use in the same configuration
inline arguments="manage.py runserver"
It says in vars:
wsgi.multithread:True
And it really is. It handles 300 req/s in one process.
Antonin

No one can ensure that the version you are currently using will last for years to come, you can try it according to your needs. If you encounter any problems, please come here to discuss.
